# Using scopes in my Pundit policy (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, pundit

How to use scopes, defined in the model, in my Pundit policy?

In my model I have a scope:

```
scope :published, ->{ where.not(published_at: nil )}
```

And in my Pundit policy I have

```
class CompanyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    def index?
        true
    end
    def create?
        user.present?
    end
    def new?
        true
    end
    def show?
        true
    end
    def update?
      user.present? && user == record.user
    end
end
```

How can I use my scope in the Pundit policy? I would like to show it only if it's "published", something like this, which doesn't work at the moment:

```
class CompanyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    def show
       record.published?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scopes are Class methods, you can't call them on instances.

You have to define a `published?` instance method too:

```
def published?
  published_at.present?
end
```

You could use the scope if you ask if the record exists on the given scope with:

```
User.published.exists?(user.id)
```

And it will return true if the scope includes the user id, but I wouldn't recommend that, it requires an extra query to the database to get something that you can know from the user instance you already have.